# What is the python equivalent of %if, %eval, %do, and %put in sas sql macros?

Tags: python, sql, sas-macro

I am trying to convert the following code from sql to python:

Sql code:

```
%macro extract(custom_nm= );

   %if %eval(&custom_nm. ne ) %then %do;
        %put ------ ABCD ABCD ------ ;
   %end;
```

Converted python code:

```
def extract(custom_nm):
```

I haven't progressed after this as I can't figure out an efficient way to convert %if, %eval, %do, and %put.

According to [SAS documentation](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/mcrolref/n18fij8dqsue9pn1lp8436e5mvb7.htm) guide,

%if expression should return true if the expression resolves to an integer other than zero and then %then clause is processed. If the expression resolves to zero, then the expression is false and the %else statement is proceeded, if it exists. If the expression resolves to a null value or non-numeric characters, then an error message is shown.

The conditions of the %eval in the [guide](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/mcrolref/n07pr39df9k7m3n1w3x1q09iewta.htm) are even longer.

Please someone who has dealt with similar function conversions above, let me know what you used.

Thank you, much appreciated.

Comment: python has all the `if` `else` etc clauses ... if you want help translating that you need to explain what it is doing not just post some sql macro thing ...

Comment: What does `&custom_nm. ne` mean?

Comment: What do you expect that function to do?  It looks like it might be saying "if custom_nm is not empty, then print "ABCD ABCD"".  That's pretty easy to translate.

Comment: `print(custom_nm or "ABCD ABCD")` maybe?

Comment: &custom_nm . ne means the macro variable custom_nm not equal to blank

Answer (score 1):

This is just an ordinary `if` statement.

```
def extract(s):
    if s:
        print("------ ABCD ABCD ------")
```